# error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

I am having table stored in database i am trying to retrieve all data in it
Why i get this error when i tried to retrieve all records in my database? 
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 185
    at warsh01.selectStmt01.getObjectIDsFromDB(selectStmt01.java:83)`

```
  public static int[] getObjectIDsFromDB (String Dbnum) throws SQLException{
    String selectSQL = "SELECT ID FROM " + Dbnum +.tabName ";
         dbConnection = getDBConnection();
         preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(selectSQL);
         ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();  
            rs.last();
            int[] rsIds=new int[rs.getRow()];
            rs.beforeFirst();
            int counter = 1;
            while (rs.next()) {
            rsIds[counter]=rs.getInt(1);
            counter++; // the error is pointing in this line 
            }
             return  rsIds;
      }
```

in the main method when i tried to run it i got the above exception

```
 int [] IdsArray ;
    pathIdsArray = getObjectIDsFromDB ("za");
   List<ObjClass>  objItm=new ArrayList<>();
   for (int i = 1; i < IdsArray.length; i++) {
    Item1 = new ObjClass ();
    objectItem1.color=Color.blue;
    objectItem1.LoadFromDB("za", IdsArray[i]);       
    objItm.add(Item1);
    }
```

Comment: i think the error should be in this line . rsIds[counter]=rs.getInt(1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ResultSets have indices starting at 1. But Java arrays have indices starting at 0. You're iterating through the result set with a counter starting at 1, and at each iteration, you initialize `rsIds[counter]`. You should initialize `rsIds[counter - 1]` instead (or start the counter at 0).

Note that using a List instead of an array would be much easier:

```
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();  
while (rs.next()) {
    result.add(rs.getInt(1));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should simply initialise `counter` to `0` instead of `1` :)

Let's say that your `ResultSet` has **4 rows**.
`rsIds` then is an `Array` of **four** `int`, from `rsIds[0]` to `rsIds[3]`.
By initialising `counter` to `1` and entering **4 times** in the `while (rs.next())` loop, you:

- never use the `rsIds[0]` value
- eventually access `rsIds[4]` (which you can't) in the last iteration.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

In Java arrays are zero indexed, i.e. the first element has the index `0`. You are using the `counter` variable to access the array's positions, but initialize it with `1`.

```
int counter = 1;
while (rs.next()) {
   rsIds[counter]=rs.getInt(1);
   counter++;
}
```

Let the row count be e.g. 5, then you have an array with five "positions" 0,1,2,3,4 . But inside the while loop you are accessing 1,2,3,4,*5* - resulting in an violation of array boundaries.